# Why is google natural language returning an incorrect beginOffset for analyzed string?

Tags: javascript, string, offset, sentiment-analysis, google-language-api

I am using google-cloud/language api to make an #annotate call and analyze entities and sentiments from a csv of comments which I have taken from various online resources.

To begin with, the string I am trying to analyze includes commentId's so I reformat this:

```
youtubez22htrtb1ymtdlka404t1aokg2kirffb53u3pya0,i just bot a Nostromo... ( ._.)﻿
youtubez22oet0bruejcdf0gacdp431wxg3vb2zxoiov1da,Good Job Baby! MSI Propeller Blade Technology!﻿
youtubez22ri11akra4tfku3acdp432h1qyzap3yy4ziifc,"exactly, i have to deal with that damned brick, and the power supply can&#39;t be upgraded because of it, because as far as power supply goes, i have never seen an external one on newegg that has more power then the x51&#39;s﻿"
youtubez23ttpsyolztc1ep004t1aokg5zuyqxfqykgyjqs,"I like how people are liking your comment about liking the fact that Sky DID put Deadlox&#39;s channel in the description instead of Ryan&#39;s. Nice Alienware thing logo thing, btw﻿"
youtubez12zjp5rupbcttvmy220ghf4ctqnerqwa04,"You know, If you actually made this. People would actually buy it.﻿"
```

So that it doesn't include any comment ID's:

```
I just bot a Nostromo... ( ._.)﻿
Good Job Baby! MSI Propeller Blade Technology!﻿\n"exactly, i have to deal with that damned brick, and the power supply can&#39;t be upgraded because of it, because as far as power supply goes, i have never seen an external one on newegg that has more power then the x51&#39;s﻿"
"I like how people are liking your comment about liking the fact that Sky DID put Deadlox&#39;s channel in the description instead of Ryan&#39;s.   Nice Alienware thing logo thing, btw﻿"
"You know, If you actually made this. People would actually buy it.﻿"
```

After sending a request for google cloud/language to #annotate the text. I receive a response which includes various substrings sentiments and magnitudes. Each string is also given a `beginOffset` value, which relates to the strings index in the original string (the string in the request).

```
{ content: 'i just bot a Nostromo... ( ._.)﻿\nGood Job Baby!',
  beginOffset: 0 }
{ content: 'MSI Propeller Blade Technology!﻿\n"exactly, i have to deal with that damned brick, and the power supply can&#39;t be upgraded because of it, because as far as power supply goes, i have never seen an external one on newegg that has more power then the x51&#39;s﻿"\n"I like how people are liking your comment about liking the fact that Sky DID put Deadlox&#39;s channel in the description instead of Ryan&#39;s.',
  beginOffset: 50 }
{ content: 'Nice Alienware thing logo thing, btw﻿"\n"You know, If you actually made this.',
  beginOffset: 462 }
```

My aim is then to locate the original comment in the original string, which should be simple enough. Something like `(originalString[beginOffset])`.....

This value is incorrect!

I am assuming that they do not include certain characters, but I have tried a multitude of regexes and nothing seems to work perfectly. Does anyone have any idea about what might be causing the issue???

Comment: Did you happen to find the solution for this? I'm having the same issue!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but the problem seems to persist even today. I have recently encountered the same issue and resolved it by interpreting Google's offsets as "byte offsets" rather than string offsets in the chosen encoding. Works great. I hope it helps someone.

The following is some C# code but anybody should be able to interpret it and recode in their own favorite language. If we assume that `text` is actually the sentiment text being analyzed then the following code transforms, Google's offsets into correct offsets.

```
int TransformOffset(string text, int offset)
{
   return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
             Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text),
             0,
             offset)
          .Length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has got something to do with encoding. Play around with one of the encodings or simply use one of the example approaches provided in their github repo:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/language/api/analyze.py

Key code block:

```py
def get_native_encoding_type():
    """Returns the encoding type that matches Python's native strings."""
    if sys.maxunicode == 65535:
        return 'UTF16'
    else:
        return 'UTF32'
```

This worked for me. It was messing up characters like `'` (that is \u2019 in unicode).

Answer (score 0):

You should set the EncodingType on the request.

Example using Java client library and working with UTF-8 encoded texts:

```
Document doc = Document.newBuilder().setContent(dreamText).setType(Type.PLAIN_TEXT).build();
        
AnalyzeEntitiesRequest request = AnalyzeEntitiesRequest.newBuilder().setEncodingType(EncodingType.UTF8).setDocument(doc).build();
```